comparing two groups in a bar plots while incorporparating lower and upper limits in R langauge
I have  data frame as below:
YOM <- c(2017, 2018, 2019)
CO <-  c(1159,910,931)
PM <- c(159,90,91)
upperlim <- c(1998,1302,1745)
lowerlim <- c(320,117,320)

data1 <- data.frame(YOM, CO, PM,  upperlim, lowerlim)


YOM <- c(2017, 2018, 2019)
CO <-  c(1169,810,931)
PM <- c(119,80,91)
upperlim <- c(2798,1102,1755)
lowerlim <- c(320,107,327)

data2 <- data.frame(YOM, CO, PM, upperlim, lowerlim)

How to combine them and obtain two bars for CO and OM as y axis values and YOM as  x axis and the upperlim and lowerlim as the limits of the bars.
like this query here but with bars and years on the x axis
Grouped bar plot in R

Do the upper and lower limits apply to both CO and PM variables?

It would be helpful if you could add some mockup of what you expect your graph to look like. If you intend to have this on one graph you can only set one upper and lower limit. So I would assume that would be max(upperlim) and min(lowerlim). Unless you are trying to create a filled bar? Generally, it is easiest to combine these into one data frame and convert it to a long format.

yes both bars have the limits

The values for PM are all lower than the lower limits for bars. Are you expecting lines below the bars? Like LMc noted, it would be helpful to see a mockup for this. Additionally, you have 2117 as a YOM value in data2, which seems like a possible typo.

This was dummy data and sometimes the bars are below the data

Bind data frames and pivot to a long format
library(tidyverse)

df <- bind_rows(data1 = data1, data2 = data2, .id = 'id') |>
  pivot_longer(c(CO,PM), names_to = 'measurement', values_to = 'value')

glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 12
#> Columns: 6
#> $ id          <chr> "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "data1", "dat…
#> $ YOM         <dbl> 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018…
#> $ upperlim    <dbl> 1998, 1998, 1302, 1302, 1745, 1745, 2798, 2798, 1102, 1102…
#> $ lowerlim    <dbl> 320, 320, 117, 117, 320, 320, 320, 320, 107, 107, 327, 327
#> $ measurement <chr> "CO", "PM", "CO", "PM", "CO", "PM", "CO", "PM", "CO", "PM"…
#> $ value       <dbl> 1159, 159, 910, 90, 931, 91, 1169, 119, 810, 80, 931, 91

Crossbars with max and min heights set by upper and lower limits

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(YOM),
             y = value,
             fill = id)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lowerlim,
                    ymax = upperlim),
                position = 'dodge') +
  facet_wrap(~measurement) +
  labs(x = 'YOM', fill = 'Data set') +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')


